# "[img]" tag formatting for x% simple visualization code and full link to directly load in 1:1 scale

Tags: formatting, bbcode

I just want to know a simple complement to the code `[img]` to get it to be shown at a X% of its original size.
I was thinking about `[img width="50%" height="50%"]` but that doesn't make any sense. Instead of a huge code, what could I place in the brackets to show the image at a X% scale?
Is that a PHP code?

And the other question. I've seen a little "tag" you could place in the direct link that could load an image into its full resolution or a lower size. I tried to find on the web, but I don't know how to describe being specific in my search criteria. For example, I pasted something like `http://example.com/image.jpg=fullscreen` and the image would load on the entire screen instead of clicking over it to zoom in. Or could it be `http://example.com/image.jpg=half` to show in half resolution.

Comment: Are talking about formatting code for SO; somewhere else? That looks like bbcode, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode

Comment: @chris85, you're totally right. I'm confusing it with BBcode in fact. Do you know how to set that?

Comment: I haven't used bbcode but maybe this would be useful, http://www.bbcode.org/examples/?id=10. I've also updated the tags of your question which should help with users specific to this tagging.

Comment: @chris85, I just read that `[img=50%] ........ [/img]` would work, but it doesn't seem to work on the forums I'm trying to place this code. It shows the literal code with the image link.

Comment: I can't offer any further help with this, sorry. I don't use bbcode, I only ended up here because of the PHP tag.

Comment: @chris85, alright. All the help is highly appreciated. Thanks for helping me out with the ambiguity I was having about this. And thanks for editing the tags of the question too. =)

Comment: I can't really help either, but for those that can, it would probably really help to add some of the forums urls into the question.  It would also help if you could look up the formatting instructions for those forums and paste in the url or the instructions of how to add images.  Alas, forums can be very different from each other, so a general answer may be impossible.

Comment: @GuySchalnat, thanks buddy, I think I have no option but to occupy the whole screen with the image. The forum support is a bit poor, but I just wanted to help with a little enhancement. By the way.. Do you know a way for the link be like the way I asked?

Comment: Combing multiple unrelated (but you might not have know that) questions do not make a good post. Consider splitting one half off in a question of its own.